# The string '26/MAR/2020 09:00 A. M.' was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index '18'

Tags: c#, angular, azure, datetime, asp.net-core

**The string '26/MAR/2020 09:00 A. M.' was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index '18'.**

As the title suggests, I'm having a problem with displaying a date on an angular webapp. In fact the date works just fine when running the api locally. The same results occur whether I'm testing from postman or the app itself. When pointing at the api locally everything works fine, when pointing at the api when hosted on azure the mentioned above error occurs. Here is some information about my environment.

1. Api: .Netcore 3.1
2. Webapp: Angular
3. Host: Azurewebsites

Here is the code when formatting the date. The name of the variable is `FechaUltimaMod`

```
string dateFormat = "d/MMM/yyyy hh:mm tt";
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es-MX");
DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi = ci.DateTimeFormat;
dtfi.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames = dtfi.AbbreviatedMonthGenitiveNames.Select(p => p.TrimEnd('.')).ToArray();
response.Select(p => { p.FechaUltimaMod = DateTime.Parse(p.FechaUltimaMod).ToString(dateFormat, ci).ToUpper(); return p; }).ToList();
```

The weird thing is that it works just fine locally, the error only occurs the the api is hosted on azure.

P.S. I do not have access to the azure account.

**Edit:**

I noticed the error message mentions unknown word starting at index '18' which happens to be the index of 'A' in the A. M. section. I did the following modification.

From:

```
string dateFormat = "d/MMM/yyyy hh:mm tt";
```

To:

```
string dateFormat = "d/MMM/yyyy hh:mm";
```

And it no longer throws the error. I don't know why, still not a fix though because I want the `tt` in the date. Just and additional fyi.

Comment: It's complaining about the time of your input string. DateTime.Parse() expects 09:00 AM when you're passing 09:00 A. M. Is there some front end component that controls the format which may be cached?

Comment: @MattAshurst The front end excepts to recieve a string(and it does), and then it just displays it on screen. Works fine locally, not when api is hosted though.